# Are you supposed to ignore the adds in boss fights?

Tags: destiny

Are the strike boss fights designed so that you are supposed to clear all the adds then focus on the boss, or will adds continue to spawn so that you can't ever really get ahead?

It's hard to tell since most of the people in queue want to rush the bosses. Traditional MMO experience tells me that the group would want to gain some breathing room first by eliminating other threats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. Destiny is an FPS, so ammo is always a consideration. One of the main points of the adds is to give the players more ammo drops while adding something to do other than shoot the boss.

That being said, it varies by strike. For some strikes you can kill the boss so quickly it won't matter (example: I just did the 9/22-9/28 Nightfall strike with specialist and void burn. With three Telestos we killed the boss in about 30 seconds). Typically, killing the adds is necessary to avoid being overwhelmed... but if you have the necessary gear you absolutely can ignore the adds. The Psion Flayers, if everyone has high level swords, can be cheesed by locking them in corners and quickly killed.

Summary: There isn't a blanket answer - it's going to depend on the strike, the difficulty level, the gear you have, the gear your teammates have, the level of co-ordination your fireteam has, and the modifiers active. When in doubt, kill the adds. The worst it'll do is make your kill take a little longer - this is, IMO, greatly preferable to dying when the boss is at 10% health because you got overwhelmed.

Answer (score 3):

The strikes are most definitely not designed to require the adds to be killed first. In every single strike the boss can both be damage and killed without killing a single add.

However, most guardians do not have the gear or are not aware of the technique to kill these bosses without paying attention to the adds.

In general, the adds will come in waves based on the life percent of the boss so that if the encounter is harder on the players they are not overwhelmed. It also means if you are more advanced you are also dealing with a now very large group of adds if the boss is taking a lot of damage.

The easy advice, kill all the things.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ammo, go for the boss. When you start to run low on ammo kill adds, or use a synth. If it's the undying mind, kill adds then work on the boss, same with the darkblade and shield brothers.

I hope this helped.